# Plone FormGen Override Subject Line

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I am new to Plone and am working a form in Plone 4.1. I would like to override the form mailer subject line so it is a string from the input from a subject field from the form and then the form name. I am not sure how to write this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the form, click on "Contents", click on the Mail-adapter, click on "Edit, click on "Overrides" and insert this line in the field "Subject Expression":

```
python: folder.Title() +  ': ' + request.form['subjekt']
```

Where `subjekt` stands for the field-name you want to get the value of.

Here's a helpful doc about the available context-variables:

https://docs.plone.org/working-with-content/managing-content/ploneformgen/override_defaults.html

Comment: Thanks for answering such a simple question! I am having a hard time with the field-name. Am I correct that the Field Label is not the field-name? Do I set a field name as the field's alias? Thank you again.

Comment: I figured this out. The field name is in the URL. Thank you again. This solved my issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad it works! No worries, concerning that even long-year developers are having problems to understand the meaning and inner workings of basic features like the expiration-date, you're doing pretty well :-)